# Cannot import .pyi file in stubs package

Tags: python

I am trying to build a package of .pyi stub files, for use with type annotations. I have this structure:

```
m/
  __init__.pyi
  sub.pyi
```

This works:

```py
>>> import m
```

This does not (including in Python 3.10):

```py
>>> import m.sub
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'm.sub'
```

If I rename `sub.pyi` to `sub.py`, then I can `import m.sub`. What am I misunderstanding about where I can use `.pyi` files, or whether I can make multi-file stubs package?

Comment: I don't think stub files are intended to be imported like that - they're read directly by the type-checking utilities that use them.

Comment: Consider this example: `from typing import Any; def f(x: Any): pass`.

If you omit the `from typing import Any`, the program cannot be imported. In my case I am defining my own type annotation types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cf [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) :

> While stub files are syntactically valid Python modules, they use the `.pyi` extension to make it possible to maintain stub files in the same directory as the corresponding real module. This also reinforces the notion that no runtime behavior should be expected of stub files.

The `.pyi` files are not meant to be used by the Python interpreter itself but by type-checking tools.
By default, a Python [loader](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loaders) will not look for `.pyi` files, so you can't import them. But you can import a package (a directory whose name matches what you are importing). That's the reason of your error.

Looking at the stubs files that PyCharm includes, the only `import`s it does is to actual `.py` files, never to `.pyi` files.